# when i read PDF data and bind image at new page the first page get different size from other page

Tags: c#, itext

when i read PDF data and bind image at new page the first page get different size from other page

I used below mentioned to for read data

```
for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber < reader.NumberOfPages + 1; pageNumber++)
        {
            document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNumber);
            int rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(pageNumber);
            //cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0f, 0f);
            document.NewPage();

        }
```

Comment: i solve this issue.

Comment: the problem is i pass static value 1 in document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1)). i change 1 to pageNumber  and it's working fine

Comment: great question!